# How to get one value from a file and ignore commented lines?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I am trying to get the value of `URL` from a `.env` file but ignore lines that start with `#`

my .env

```
URL=staging
#URL=prod
OTHER_VAR=test
```

I am trying to save the value of `URL` inside of a variable using `grep`

Here is what I have:

```
MY_VAR=$(grep URL ./.env | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
```

I have tried to use:

```
MY_VAR=$(grep -v '^#' ./.env | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
```

but don't know how to specify which variable I want to get the value from

Comment: `MY_VAR="$(sed -n 's/^URL=//p' ./.env)";`?

Comment: with GNU grep: `grep -oP '^URL=\K.+'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, thanks, it seems to work. How does it exclude `#`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match those lines that begin with `URL=` and get the value after this text only using a single `sed` command:

```
MY_VAR="$(sed -n 's/^URL=//p' ./.env)";
```

Here, `-n` suppresses the default line output, `s/^URL=//` removes `URL=` at the start of the matched line (`^` is the start of string anchor) and `p` prints the result, i.e. what is after `URL=`.

If there can be whitespace before `URL=`, you may add `[[:space:]]*` after `^`:

```
MY_VAR="$(sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*URL=//p' ./.env)";
```

[@Sundeep's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576242/how-to-grep-one-value-from-a-file-and-ignore-commented-lines/61576385#comment108921417_61576242) PCRE-based `grep`  command works similarly. `grep -oP '^URL=\K.+' ./.env` or `grep -oP '^\s*URL=\K.+' ./.env` will yield the same results as above `sed` commands (in a PCRE pattern, you may match whitespaces with `\s` shorthand character class).